# update fancybox current slide content on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I want to update content of current slide on according to content type. 
If I try setting content, instead of showing pdf or image it only shows html string.

Here is my code:

```
    $("#fancywork-manual-b").click(function() {
  $.fancybox.open([{
        src: '<a id="btn_click" class="btn" href="#">clickme</a>',
        type: 'html',
        smallBtn: false,
        buttons: [
          'close',
          'fullScreen'
        ]

      }

    ],

    {
      afterShow: function(instance) {
        $("#btn_click").click(function() {
          $.fancybox.getInstance().setContent($.fancybox.getInstance().current, 'https://source.unsplash.com/ndjyaOp0fOc/1600x900');
        })
      }
    }


  );
});
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqwoxB)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That is because you declared the type to be html. It should be 'iframe'

Comment: how can I set content type on button click? because `setContent` only accepts two `params`, one is `slide` and other is `content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1) Open new instance and close current one:

```
afterShow: function(instance) {
    $("#btn_click").click(function() {

        $.fancybox.open({
            src : 'https://source.unsplash.com/ndjyaOp0fOc/1600x900',
            type : 'image'
        });

        instance.close();
    });

}
```

2) If you really want to reuse current instance, you would need to update `group` and `slide` objects. It would be easier to completely replace both and then use `jumpTo` method to activate:

```
afterShow: function(instance) {
    $("#btn_click").click(function() {

        var f = $.fancybox.getInstance();

        f.group  = [];
        f.slides = {};

        f.createGroup({
            src : 'https://source.unsplash.com/ndjyaOp0fOc/1600x900',
            type : 'image'
        });

        f.jumpTo( 0 )

    })
}
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOgPzy?editors=1010